# What's the exact meaning of 'showstopper'?

Tags: word-usage

I encountered many times that my prospects asked for some must-have features as some 'showstopper' features. In those cases, I understood a showstopper is a mandatory requirement. But on the hand, I got the explanation for showstopper in Merriam-Webster as 'an act, song, or performer that receives so much applause that the performance is interrupted', which seems is talking about a very good but not necessarily mandatory thing. So how do we use the word showstopper?

Comment: You are probably right that the meaning of the term has gotten twisted over the years.  Currently, in the computer industry, I'm most familiar with it meaning "something bad that must be fixed to continue".  The meaning you describe of "something (presumably) good that is required to continue" is somewhere between that meaning and the original.  This is how the language morphs over time.

Comment: In fact, I'm fairly confident that the term has been twisted by it's use in business by those who are not aware of its etymology (which I was vaguely aware of but never considered at length).  They heard the term a few times in presentations, misunderstood it's meaning, then reused it with exactly the opposite meaning.  Certainly this transformation may have been going on ca 1980 when I first heard the term in business meetings. (I was familiar with "stop the show" (in the "good" sense) from reading stories ca 1960, but didn't connect it with "show stopper" when I heard that term in meetings.)

Comment: (I should note that I can claim innocence from having participated in the transformation, since no one was ever foolish enough to have me give a presentation at these meetings.  The most I can claim is originating the briefly-popular idiom "plan du jour".)

Answer (score 4):

A 'showstopper' features is called that because the absence of it will 'stop the show', i.e. cause the product not to be released. Showstopper bugs and problems have similar meaning. It is only tangentially related to the entertainment meaning of 'showstopper'.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of software development (and the same is probably true for other product development) I haven't heard of a "showstopper feature". You can have "showstopper problems": If you are preparing to release a product, a "showstopper" problem, or in short a "showstopper" is one that must absolutely be solved before the product can be released.